# stderr: fatal: unable to access 'bitbucket': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins, kubernetes

I have deployed a Jenkins on K8s and execute a new build the Jenkins system will call K8s cloud to create a k8s pod for the build. 
I have created a job using git as source management control but when I build this job I got this issue.

I tried to disable git SSL by command below on Jenkins master (k8s Jenkins pod) and slave (the pod is called when build executes) then I'm trying exec to Jenkins master and slave pod by manual to check out my repos and it's work but When I execute the job then I still got this issue.

`git config --global http.sslVerify false`

Full log in Jenkins:

```
Started by user admin
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to https://mybitbucket.com/scm/tm/myrepository.git/
 > git config remote.origin.url https://mybitbucket.com/scm/tm/myrepository.git/ # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials bitbucket
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 1 remote branch
Obtained Jenkinsfile from ba534dd598f9fa4131e056c2b7faa478042876e5
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] readTrusted
Obtained apppod.yaml from ba534dd598f9fa4131e056c2b7faa478042876e5
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘app-pod’
Agent app-pod-dz52j-6qx1t is provisioned from template Kubernetes Pod Template
Agent specification [Kubernetes Pod Template] (app-pod): 

Running on app-pod-dz52j-6qx1t in /home/jenkins/workspace/Application_master
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential bitbucket
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --progress -- https://mybitbucket.com/scm/tm/myrepository.git/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://mybitbucket.com/scm/tm/myrepository.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2430)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2044)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:81)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:569)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:798)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:161)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:154)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 10.32.0.1/10.32.0.1:44550
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1788)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:998)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1323.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1122)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1167)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a MITM SSL device on your network?  Does the server have a proper SSL certificate from a trusted certificate authority, or are you using a self-signed certificate or in-house CA?  Also, what operating system are you using here?